# Kinect robotic arm detection

Tags: image-processing, kinect, robotics, motion-detection, lbr-iiwa-rapi

can i use Kinect sensor to detect the motion of a robotic arm (KUKA LBR iiwa 7R800) and calculate it's links angles in order to make it control another robotic arm.

Comment: Using a Kinect to accurately detect and track a robotic arm with all it's joints sounds overly complicated. Can you not connect the 1st robotic arm (via serial connection or what interface it supports) to simply read each motor's value, then send/write those values to the second arm ?

Comment: what's the motivation? what's the second robot type?

Comment: Thank you, sorry i don't understand what do you mean by serial connection yo read each motors value, the motors we have does not have a position feedback

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible but I don't think it is a good idea.

Suboptimal accuracy, lag due to processing of the 3d-data. I guess there are also cases where you cannot see all joints/links.

Kuka robots can output their joint angles directly. Use this data for synchronization or control both robots using the same external data.

Any measurement error might cause unwanted movements which in case of industrial robots can cause severe damage!

Comment: Thank you, the KUKA robot we have is made in our university using stepper motors so we can not take a position feedback from the motors i think, and there is no place for encoders in the design so i thought we can take the position feedback by using image processing.but i think that there will be measurement error as you say.

Comment: how  can it be a Kuka if you build in your Universtity with stepper motors? I'm confused.
Something controls the robot. If you don't have position feedback just input the same data to both robots. As you don't have position feedback you will never know if both robots move properly anyway.

Comment: @MohanadMansour are you sending angles to the first arm (using forward kinematics) or an end effector position and orientation (using inverse kinematics) ? Either way, if you're controlling stepper motors, you'll need to calculate the positions before sending them to the first arm, so you should be able to send the same stepper motor positions to the second arm